# I am trying to make the border-bottom in CSS responsive, so when i zoom in, it does not become super thick

Tags: css, responsive-design

As the title states, I am trying to make my CSS responsive. I have a `border-bottom: solid 0.5rem white;`
line of code and I was wondering if there was an alternative sizing option to make the border-bottom responsive, so it shrinks instead of grows as I zoom into the web page.

I have tried multiple values in the border size field.
Any other ideas?

```css
header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 0.5% white;
    background-color: white;
    height: 5.3rem;
    background-image: url(./Images/sunset.JPG);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
```

I tried to put a pixel value, em, rem, vh, etc. to make it so when I zoom in on the webpage, and head towards a mobile view, the bottom border gets taller and taller making it so thick, the page looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your positioning looks good - hard to tell without a codepen...so I made one.

I set the border-bottom to "solid 1px #abc123" --> I generally use that color to stand out. White on a white border isn't visible.

I checked it on mobile and at 1px, it doesn't seem obnoxiously large. Hope this helps:

https://codepen.io/Graham-Tucker/pen/QWYYBJm

```
header {
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: solid 1px #abc123;
background-color: white;
height: 5.3rem;
background-image: url(./Images/sunset.JPG);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top;
background-size: 100% 100%;
top: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
margin-left: -8px;}
.imgxpls {margin: 10px auto 10px auto; max-width: 600px;}
.imgxpls img {width: 100%; height: auto}

<HTML><header><p>Something here</p><hr/><p>Something else below</p>
</header>
<div class="imgxpls"><img src="https://outrightsites.com/wp-content/themes/altimeter_2020/img/wiki-commons-space-01.jpg" /></div>
<div class="imgxpls"><img src="https://outrightsites.com/wp-content/themes/altimeter_2020/img/wiki-commons-space-02.jpg" /></div>
<div class="imgxpls"><img src="https://outrightsites.com/wp-content/themes/altimeter_2020/img/wiki-commons-space-03.jpg" /></div>
</html>
```

Comment: I used 1px because a "px" is a static unit that does NOT increase in size with zoom.